# How can I host a php script on a dotnet core web app hosted at Azure

Tags: php, azure, web, web-config, .net-core

so I am trying to get a php script to run on a dotnet core web app in Azure.

I added some php scripts to the wwwroot/php/ folder.

I assumed it would be as easy as going to domain.com/php/script.php in order to execute this script. But I only get 404 when I do. I have verified that the file is there so I am not sure why I get 404s..

Is there anything else I need to do in order for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a Virtual directory to achieve this. From the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com), select your app service and click on **Application settings**, then scroll down to **Virtual applications and directories**. Just enter your virtual directory and the physical path as below, after that done click **Save** button.

[image]